# Let $S^3 = \{(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 | ||z_1||^2 + ||z_2||^2 = 1\}$, $D^2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} | ||z|| \leq 1\}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $S^3 = \{(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 | ||z_1||^2 + ||z_2||^2 = 1\}$, $D^2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} | ||z|| \leq 1\}$. Let $X$ be the quotient of the disjoint union of $D^2$ and $S^3$ by the smallest equivalence relation identifying $z \in D^2$, $||z|| = 1,$ with $(z^2, 0) \in S^3$. Calculate the homology of $X$.

Comment: I do not know how to start.  Its impossible to visualize.

Comment: Have you considered using Mayer-Vietoris?

Comment: but on what?  I can't picture it.

Comment: Suppose it was only $S^1$ you were gluing in instead of $D^2$. If you made the quotient space of $S^1$ given by $e^{i\theta}\sim e^{i2\theta}$ you would be left with a circle still (but with half the circumference). Now, extend trivially (ie make now new identifications) this quotient map from the boundary of $D^2$ to the entire disc. Also, extend it from the equator circle of $S^3$ to the entire $3$-sphere. These are the two space you are gluing together along the quotient circle.

Comment: I don't see it. :(

Comment: Try doing the problem just in the case when you're identifying $z\in\partial D^2$ with $(z,0)\in S^3$. You can get a rough idea of how this looks by imaging taking a disk and then capping it on either end with a hemi-sphere (this would be in the case of $S^2$ not $S^3$ so it's not a perfect analogy) so that you get a sphere with a disk glued along its boundary.